# How to use RFE for RF and SVM

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, feature-selection, svm, recursive-model

Considering I have a big data (lots of OTUs and clinical), which I will be using to input into RF and SVM for prediction (classification), will it make sense to **perform RFE as a feature selection step?**

What **method for RFE** should I apply for RF and SVM? Since I believe that RF and SVM can be used as methods for RFE but would applying RF-RFE to RF (and the same for SVM) be redundant? I am unsure how exactly to perform RFE for RF/SVM (i.e., workflow).